# Can keras directly read images from a directory?

Tags: python, keras

I am working on a project of self driving car, using Raspberry Pi. I have collected the frames and I have the path to each image in a log, which is in csv format. Can I give this path (which is in string form) to keras, so that it can look at those images, while training. My data format looks like this -

[data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKjxt.png)

Does keras have this feature that it can read files/images directly from the path(which is in string form). Or we have to process these paths so that it can be fed to keras. Thanks in advance for kind support.

Comment: Are all the images located in the same directory?

Comment: you can use load_img from keras.preprocessing import image

Comment: I was not allowed to insert the image of the data format, so I have given the link for it. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Yes all the images are located in the same directory.

Comment: @Raj in that case you can use the [flow_from_directory](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory) or [flow_from_dataframe](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_dataframe) judging from what I'm seeing in your question.

Comment: @Alexander Ejbekov could you please tell me an implementation of flow_from_directory and flow_from_dataframe.

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-image-classification-with-keras-flow-from-directory-and-generators-95f75ebe5720).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, take a look on flow_from_dataframe.

[Tutorial](https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-on-keras-imagedatagenerator-with-flow-from-dataframe-8bd5776e45c1)